# GCC and NASM link to external library

Tags: gcc, command-line, nasm, undefined-reference

I want to create a simple application in Assembly (with NASM) that will get the command line arguments. For now I use `extern _GetCommandLineA` and `call _GetCommandLineA` to call the function. I compile the code and get the object file from NASM.
Now I wanna use GCC to link and create the EXE. I don't want to use the standard libraries, so I use this command to build the executable:

```
gcc test.obj -s -nostartfiles -nostdlib -nodefaultlibs -o test.exe
```

It gets me an `Undefined reference to GetCommandLineA` error and, as a beginner in ASM, I don't know why? Some help would really be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetCommandLineA` and `GetCommandLineW` are defined in `kernel32.dll` which, like most of the Windows API, uses the [WINAPI (stdcall) calling convention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxk0tw93(v=vs.71).aspx).

In order to call this function from assembly, you will need to specify the fully "decorated" symbol name, in this case `_GetCommandLineA@0`

**Replace `_GetCommandLineA` in your assembly file with `_GetCommandLineA@0`**